# Loop in javascript from list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I have my api which is returning response like this :

```
"imagePath": "path1",
```

I have JS code like this below :

```
<div className="flexAlignCenterJustifyCenter">
  {event.imagePath ? (
    <img
      src={event.imagePath}
      onError={(event) => event.target.src = NoImage}
    />
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
</div>
```

So properly it is showing the image,

but now I changed my api to give the output as a list which is :

```
"imagePath": ["path1","path2"]
```

now the NoImage icon is showing, and I want to display all the images in the list (imagePath) , I am new to javascript can anyone pls help me out?

Comment: You can use `imagePath.forEach((path)=>{ //you have the image path here })` to loop through each path and set them in the image elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your response is now an array, you should iterate through it, for example with `.map`:

```
<div className="flexAlignCenterJustifyCenter">
{ 
  event.map((data, index) => {
    return <img key={index} src={data.imagePath} onError={(data)=>{data.target.src=NoImage}} /> 
  }
}
</div>
```